# Answer marked as solution. If deleted, is questioner free to mark another answer as the solution?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

A questioner marked my answer as the solution, despite giving new information pointing out it was not the right answer after all. If I remove my answer, is the solution flag reset and available again?

[The actual question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683100/low-noise-stable-power-source-options/683123#683123)

Comment: The asker is free to accept a different answer at any time, or unaccept all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you can't delete your own answer if it is accepted so it's not quite that simple.

If a moderator or a group of trusted users deleted your answer then, yes the person who asked the question could accept another answer.

Note that acceptance simply means the answer helped the asker of the question the most. It doesn't really mean it's the solution.

And finally, if you think another answer is better than yours, feel free to upvote that answer.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'd like the other answer get the credit, but it is what it is. Other users reading the comments will understand.

Comment: @MiNiMe if you feel like your answer is incorrect and the accepted status is preventing it from being deleted, use a custom moderator flag to explain the situation and request your answer be deleted.

Comment: I'll leave it as it is since it's a valid answer for the question before additional information was given. The comments gives the whole picture.

Comment: Ideally the asker would have asked another question rather than changing the one asked in such a way that it invalidated any of the existing answers.